# How can I convert an 2D int array into a 2D String array with Streams?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, java-8, java-stream

I am attempting to convert a 2D int array into a 2D String array with this code:

```
Arrays.stream(intArray).map(a -> 
    Arrays.stream(a).map(i -> 
        Integer.toString(i)).toArray()).toArray(String[][]::new);
```

but I get the compile-time error `cannot convert from String to int` when doing `Integer.toString(i)`. I thought it could be because I'm collecting the results of streaming an `int` array in a `String` array, but doesn't `map` create a new `Collection`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Arrays.stream` on an `int[]` returns an `IntStream`, and to go from an `int` to a `String` or any other `Object`, you have to use the `IntStream.mapToObj` method, not the `map` method:

```
Arrays.stream(intArray).map(a -> 
    Arrays.stream(a).mapToObj(i -> 
        Integer.toString(i)).toArray(String[]::new)).toArray(String[][]::new);
```

The `map` method of `IntStream` is only used to map from an `int` to an `int`.